# Action URLs from CP to a Craft 3 plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, error, controller

I'm working on my first Craft 3 plugin and want to add some buttons to my plugin's control panel section which post form data to a controller.

My plugin is called 'myplugin', the controller I wish to post to is called 'products' and the method in that controller is 'get-products'. I figured I should therefore create the URL on the forms as

```
{{ actionUrl('products/get-products') }}
```

However this yields a 404 error

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Page not found.
↵
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
Unable to resolve the request "https:/local.mydomain.co.uk/index.php?p=admin/actions/products/get-products".
in /Users/pete/projects/myclient/dev/build/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 537
```

If I call the URL directly by using `https://local.mydomain.co.uk/admin/actions/myplugin/products/get-products` then it behaves as expected.

Obviously I'm missing some really important bit of knowledge here and would love if someone could help me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `{{ actionUrl('myplugin/products/get-products') }}`.

But in a form, it's maybe even better/easier to use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myplugin/products/get-products" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked initially.  When performing that request from the front-end it works OK. But I have worked out what is wrong and can get it working using the latter suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was two-fold and partly related to my plugin requiring POST data.

If I set the URL to `myplugin/products/get-products` then it hits the correct controller.

I then set the form method to `post` and added the necessary `{{ csrfInput() }}` tag to generate the CSRF fields in the form.

Using `{{ actionUrl() }}` still doesn't work but I figured that's because it creates a GET request.

Comment: ActionUrl() does not create a get request. It creates a URL. If you'd use that and set the form's method to POST, it would work.

Comment: I used the incorrect terminology. It creates a url with querystring parameters such as index.php?p=admin/actions/myplugin/products/get-products. Adding a method parameter of POST to the form didn't seem to make a difference to that generated URL.